# LibGdx KeyUp Not Working

Tags: libgdx

When using the following code

```
public static boolean isDown;

public boolean keyDown(int key) {
    if (key == Keys.SPACE) {
        isDown = true;
        KeyMethods.testKeyDown();
    }
    if (key == Keys.DOWN) {
        KeyMethods.testKeyPressed();
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean keyUp(int key) {
    if (key == Keys.SPACE) {
        isDown = false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The keyUp is not setting the isDow to false. The testKeyDown:

```
public static void testKeyDown() {
    while (GameKeyListener.isDown) {
        System.out.println("Down");

    }
}
```

It just creates an infinite loop. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return true at the very end of the keyDown/keyUp methods. this indicates that the event is handled.